# Prometheus windows exporter - multiple directories with textfiles to read

Tags: prometheus

I have 3 folders with some .prom files (let's call them test1...3) that I want to read in single service put on port 9182, my config file looks like this:

```
collectors:
  enabled: textfile
collector:
  service:
    services-where: Name='windows_exporter'
  scheduled_task:
    include: /Microsoft/.+
  textfile:
    directory: C:\Users\ms\Desktop\test1\
log:
  level: debug
scrape:
  timeout-margin: 0.5
telemetry:
  path: /metrics
  max-requests: 5
web:
  listen-address: ":9182"
```

Is there a way to make it read .prom files in other folders? I tried

```
directory: C:\Users\ms\Desktop\test1\
directory: C:\Users\ms\Desktop\test2\
directory: C:\Users\ms\Desktop\test3\
```

but it's not working, also after using coma. Documentation isn't very clear about that but I am almost sure that I've done it once and just cannot remember how.

Comment: Based on [this file](https://github.com/prometheus-community/windows_exporter/blob/master/collector/textfile.go) I don't believe windows_exporter supports multiple directories for scraping textfile-based metrics.